# Setting Group Owner using workflow 2013 and REST

Tags: 2013, workflow, rest

We wanted to have a group created while specifying the group owner upon creation. Is that possible?

The rest call to /_api/currentsite/sitegroups using POST will create a group, but there is an "Owner" field that I'm trying to specify, and the type is an "SP.Principal" but I'm not sure how to do that...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Powershell and CSOM to do this so there has to be a way to do it in REST I would think.

```
Function Set-GroupOwner{

    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,HelpMessage="The URL of the site collection",Position=0)][ValidateNotNull()]
        [string]$SiteUrl,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,HelpMessage="The group that needs updated",Position=1)][ValidateNotNull()]
        [string]$GroupToUpdate,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,HelpMessage="The desired group owner",Position=2)][ValidateNotNull()]
        [string]$GroupOwner

    )
    $context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl)
    $context.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($credential.UserName, $credential.Password)

    $owner = $context.Web.SiteGroups.GetByName($GroupOwner)
    $group = $context.Web.SiteGroups.GetByName($GroupToUpdate)

    $group.Owner = $owner
    $group.Update()
    $context.ExecuteQuery()

    $context.Dispose()
}
```

I adapted it from  https://stackoverflow.com/a/25654742/318776. Hope it helps.

Comment: I know how to do this using Powershell and CSOM, but rest within workflow 2013 has it's limitations so I'd like to found out if it's possible to set the Owner on creation using SharePoint Designer 2013 workflows.

Comment: I think it'd just be passing in the string of the group owner

Comment: I thought so too, Owner and OwnerId to the Workflow Context -> Initator -> UserID (as Integer) turns up with the error code "A PrimitativeValue node with non-null value was found" and "property 'OwnerId' does not exist.." respectively. Not sure where to turn from here. Any other ideas?

Comment: ok, I'll try the loginname...

Comment: If it functions like Powershell, the display name would be my guess

Comment: loginname doesn't work, setting the dictionary {__metadata: type{ SP.Group} } Owner: (LoginName)} doesn't work. I'm trying to find whats the matter...

Comment: Looks like it may be a bug: http://www.jrjlee.com/2014/01/custom-workflow-activity-for-setting.html

Comment: even though it's a bug, this is the correct answer for it.